# How to install Cassandra on macOS?

Tags: java, macos, cassandra, macos-mojave

How to install cassandra on macOS Mojave? Please help me with the steps needs to be followed?
Getting error while running the below command:

```
cassandra -f

intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps mentioned in below URL to install Cassandra on mac

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/install/installMacdse.html

Answer (score 0):

This error has more to do with your JRE version than the OS you are running.  Setting `ThreadPriorityPolicy=42` works in Java 8, but not any major version higher than that.

There is not a current version of Cassandra which uses anything higher than Java 8, so I recommend you ensure that the latest patch of that version is installed.

**tl;dr;**

- Install Java 1.8
- Try running Cassandra again